# linux python single file double click to run

Tags: linux, python, double-click

I'm using Ubuntu Linux and have my python files setup so that when I double click them it opens my text editor to edit them since most of my python files are "work-in-progress."  However a few of my python files are in a "finished" state and I don't plan on editing them often, just running them.  Is there a way to make those files double click to run instead of edit - on an individual basis?  Or a way to encapsulate them some type of container to double click?

Answer (score 2):

You can write wrapper scripts like this:

filename: `foobar`

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import foobar
foobar.main()
```

filename: `foobar.py`

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
....
(actual code)
....
def main():
  ...
if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Then `chmod +x foobar`. To edit doubleclick on `foobar.py` and to run doubleclick on `foobar`.

This follows the unix/linux convention that executables have no extension and the python convention that the source files have a `.py` extension.

Comment: Will work but will effectively double the number of files he has

Answer (score 1):

As you're using file associations to edit them I suggest when you've finished them you rename them to something else (eg. blah.pyx) and then associate .pyx with execute.

Make sure you have this at the top of each ofc:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Answer (score 0):

Asociate the .py file, right click `file.py` select properties/open with, then select Other application at the bottom you see a + Use a custom command, Click and use

```
xterm -e python2
```